# Opencart v3 call webhook

Tags: opencart

Is there a way to provide a url for opencart v3 to call after an order is completed? I want the order details posted to this url.

I couldn't find any extensions or any way in the sertings to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could add a CURL to the order success page but you must remember some users will simply close the browser after placing payment on PayPal so in that case your URL would not be called.